# AutoMapper don't work with entity EF Core

Tags: c#, odata, automapper, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to get view from entity with fields that I specify at expandProperties with .ProjectTo(). Using .Net Core 2 + Ef Core + AutoMapper

There is entities:

```
public class LessonCatalog {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? ImageId { get; set; }
    public virtual Image Image { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Lesson> Lessons { get; set; }
}

public class Lesson {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int? ImageId { get; set; }
    public virtual Image Image { get; set; }
    public int LessonCatalogId { get; set; }
    public virtual LessonCatalog LessonCatalog { get; set; }
}
```

Views:

```
public class LessonView {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int? ImageId { get; set; }
    public ImageView Image { get; set; }
    public int LessonCatalogId { get; set; }
    public LessonCatalogView LessonCatalog { get; set; }
}

public class LessonCatalogView {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? ImageId { get; set; }
    public ImageView Image { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<LessonView> Lessons { get; set; }
}
```

My maps:

```
CreateMap<LessonCatalog, LessonCatalogView>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Image, map => map.ExplicitExpansion())
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Lessons, map => map.ExplicitExpansion());

CreateMap<Lesson, LessonView>()
             .ForMember(dest => dest.LessonCatalog, map => map.ExplicitExpansion());
```

In my repository:

```
protected readonly DbContext _context;
protected readonly DbSet<TEntity> _entities;

    public Repository(DbContext context) {
        _context = context;
        _entities = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

public IEnumerable<TView> GetOData<TView>(ODataQueryOptions<TView> query,
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate = null) {

        IQueryable<TEntity> repQuery = _entities.AsQueryable();
        IQueryable res;
        if (predicate != null) repQuery = _entities.Where(predicate);

        if (query != null) {
            string[] expandProperties = GetExpands(query);
            //!!!
            res = repQuery.ProjectTo<TView>(Mapper.Configuration, expandProperties);
            //!!!
            var settings = new ODataQuerySettings();
            var ofilter = query.Filter;
            var orderBy = query.OrderBy;
            var skip = query.Skip;
            var top = query.Top;

            if (ofilter != null) res = ofilter.ApplyTo(res, settings);
            if (orderBy != null) res = orderBy.ApplyTo(res, settings);
            if (skip != null) res = skip.ApplyTo(res, settings);
            if (top != null) res = top.ApplyTo(res, settings);
        } else {
            res = repQuery.ProjectTo<TView>(Mapper.Configuration);
        }

        return (res as IQueryable<TView>).AsEnumerable();
    }
```

`expandProperties` consist "Lessons" string, but after `.ProjectTo()` I have null at Lessons field, and it's the same for all other entities at my project.

In the same ASP .Net 4.5 project with Entity FrameWork it's works fine.
I feel I missing something important, at this case.
There is may be a better way to get View with properties that I specify at odata expand query.

My packages: AutoMapper 6.2.2, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.0, Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData 7.0.0-beta 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are hitting the wrong `ProjectTo` overload.

```
repQuery.ProjectTo<TView>(Mapper.Configuration, expandProperties);
```

is calling

```
public static IQueryable<TDestination> ProjectTo<TDestination>(
    this IQueryable source,
    IConfigurationProvider configuration,
    object parameters,
    params Expression<Func<TDestination, object>>[] membersToExpand
);
```

i.e. the `expandProperties` maps to `object parameters` argument and have no effect.

Make sure you call `ProjectTo` overload having `params string[] membersToExpand` argument, for instance

```
repQuery.ProjectTo<TView>(Mapper.Configuration, null, expandProperties);
```

which matches

```
public static IQueryable<TDestination> ProjectTo<TDestination>(
    this IQueryable source,
    IConfigurationProvider configuration,
    IDictionary<string, object> parameters,
    params string[] membersToExpand
);
```

Comment: thank you) I lost my mind)
I remove localization from another project and forget about order of params