# AutoMapper with EF Core doesn't return OData @count correctly if using $top

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, odata, automapper

I'm using the solution provided by this link: [AutoMapper don't work with entity EF Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48662826/automapper-dont-work-with-entity-ef-core/57384700#57384700)

My problem is when using $top, @odata.count always return the number informed in $top but should return the number of total record.

I know that ODataQueryOptions has a property “Count”, but I don't know if it's possible to use to solve the problem

I'm using the below the code provided by Дмитрий Краснов  in his question including the solution by Ivan Stoev:

There is entities:

```cs
public class LessonCatalog {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? ImageId { get; set; }
    public virtual Image Image { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Lesson> Lessons { get; set; }
}

public class Lesson {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int? ImageId { get; set; }
    public virtual Image Image { get; set; }
    public int LessonCatalogId { get; set; }
    public virtual LessonCatalog LessonCatalog { get; set; }
}
Views:

public class LessonView {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int? ImageId { get; set; }
    public ImageView Image { get; set; }
    public int LessonCatalogId { get; set; }
    public LessonCatalogView LessonCatalog { get; set; }
}

public class LessonCatalogView {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? ImageId { get; set; }
    public ImageView Image { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<LessonView> Lessons { get; set; }
}
```

My maps:

```
CreateMap<LessonCatalog, LessonCatalogView>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Image, map => map.ExplicitExpansion())
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Lessons, map => map.ExplicitExpansion());

CreateMap<Lesson, LessonView>()
             .ForMember(dest => dest.LessonCatalog, map => map.ExplicitExpansion());
In my repository:

protected readonly DbContext _context;
protected readonly DbSet<TEntity> _entities;

    public Repository(DbContext context) {
        _context = context;
        _entities = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

public IEnumerable<TView> GetOData<TView>(ODataQueryOptions<TView> query,
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate = null) {

        IQueryable<TEntity> repQuery = _entities.AsQueryable();
        IQueryable res;
        if (predicate != null) repQuery = _entities.Where(predicate);

        if (query != null) {
            string[] expandProperties = GetExpands(query);
            //!!!
            res = repQuery.ProjectTo<TView>(Mapper.Configuration, null, expandProperties);
            //!!!
            var settings = new ODataQuerySettings();
            var ofilter = query.Filter;
            var orderBy = query.OrderBy;
            var skip = query.Skip;
            var top = query.Top;

            if (ofilter != null) res = ofilter.ApplyTo(res, settings);
            if (orderBy != null) res = orderBy.ApplyTo(res, settings);
            if (skip != null) res = skip.ApplyTo(res, settings);
            if (top != null) res = top.ApplyTo(res, settings);
        } else {
            res = repQuery.ProjectTo<TView>(Mapper.Configuration);
        }

        return (res as IQueryable<TView>).AsEnumerable();
    }
```

If my query result has 1007 records, and I use

```
…$count=true&$top=5
```

the result for count should be

```
"@odata.count": 1007
```

But instead the result is always

```
"@odata.count": 5
```

Using SQL Server Profile I can see that the Select for count is including the “top”. So, how to avoid this to happen?

Answer (score 0):

I received a help from the Github Guy (thanks to @Gennady Pundikov) and could now answer this question.

I changed the GetOData Method to get the Count before apply others settings:

```
public IEnumerable<TView> GetOData<TView>(ODataQueryOptions<TView> query,
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate = null) {

        IQueryable<TEntity> repQuery = _entities.AsQueryable();
        IQueryable res;
        if (predicate != null) repQuery = _entities.Where(predicate);

        if (query != null) {
            string[] expandProperties = GetExpands(query);
            //!!!
            res = repQuery.ProjectTo<TView>(Mapper.Configuration, null, expandProperties);
            //!!!
            var settings = new ODataQuerySettings();
            var ofilter = query.Filter;
            var orderBy = query.OrderBy;
            var skip = query.Skip;
            var top = query.Top;

            if (ofilter != null) res = ofilter.ApplyTo(res, settings);
            if (query.Count?.Value == true)
            {
                // We should calculate TotalCount only with filter
                // http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/odata-v4.0-part2-url-conventions.html#_Toc371341773
                // 4.8 Addressing the Count of a Collection
                // "The returned count MUST NOT be affected by $top, $skip, $orderby, or $expand.
                query.Request.ODataFeature().TotalCount = ((IQueryable<TView>)res).LongCount();
            }

            if (top != null) res = top.ApplyTo(res, settings);
            if (orderBy != null) res = orderBy.ApplyTo(res, settings);
            if (skip != null) res = skip.ApplyTo(res, settings);
        } else {
            res = repQuery.ProjectTo<TView>(Mapper.Configuration);
        }

        return (res as IQueryable<TView>).AsEnumerable();
    }
```